# Karaoke Music App

Tags: iphone, core-data

> I want to create Karaoke type app. My app will take music from itunes
>   and save it in sqlite database from application's document folder.Then
>   I have to save music title, album name and artist name. I want to save
>   lyrics with time stamps.so that I could display lyrics when music starts playing and highlight each letter of lyrics. I am stuck here. How can I create dynamic
>   time stamps in data base. because each music file may be of different
>   duration.I want to use code data. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no way to predict in software where a word appears in a song, or what the structure of the song is, you will need to make a series of timestamps for each word manually, timing it yourself (or the user will)

Comment: yes. I am confused about maintaining database of timestamps for each song with lyrics

Comment: @iProgrammer You guys can take a look at lrc files. This person has actually did it using lrc files. [link to his Github](https://github.com/cherrythia/VTXKaraokeLyricView)